# Is backlinking possible in drupal 7?

Tags: navigation

Is there a way to tell what pages within the site link back to a particular page within the site?

Answer (score 1):

Create a view of the pages with, for example, a list of tiles linked to the content. Then create a contextual filter using the entity reference field. In the Contextual Filter configuration for the entity reference, select 'Provide default value > Content ID from URL' under 'When the filter value is NOT available'.

Set the view to display as a block on the page, and it will display a list of the titles referencing that page.